# New user event handler in ASP.NET Login Control

Tags: asp.net, login-control, servercontrols

I have a login control in my asp.net web site. Each user has default data inserted to my DB when registered so i was thinking of an event handler when a new user is registered but i can only find `OnLoggedIn` and `OnLoggingIn`. I could check the DB each time a user logs in but this would be not elegant. Is there a `OnRegistered` event handler or something of this sort?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If youre using the user creation wizard, it has a [CreatingUser event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.creatinguser(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks - found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386691/how-do-i-get-user-id-for-new-registered-user-in-asp-net-createuserwizard